# Update table column by AJAX in Wicket

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

I have a AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable table witch some text column (PropertyColumn). The table contains also a column with editable text fields. I'd like to update by AJAX one of the PropertyColumn, but I don't want to update the entire table.
How can I do that?

Comment: Don't you mind sharing with us at least a relevant piece of your efforts - just in support of [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: We dont even know *when* you want to update that one column ..

Comment: Robert, that is what I looking for (inter component Events).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Wicket 6 you could use inter component Events.

First create an event which holds the `AjaxRequestTarget` like this:

```
public class AjaxUpdateEvent {
    private final AjaxRequestTarget target;

    public AjaxUpdateEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        this.target = target;
    }
    public AjaxRequestTarget getAjaxRequestTarget() {
        return target;
    }
}
```

You can send such an event form any `Component` you want using the `send()` method. You send events like this:

`send(getPage(), Broadcast.DEPTH, new AjaxUpdateEvent(target));`

Then in the `AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable` i would try to override newCellItem and listen there for the event when fired from somewhere sometime and add the desired cell item to the AjaxRequestTarget. Something like that:

```
    AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable table =
            new AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable("table", null, null, FLAG_RESERVED1) {
        @Override
        protected Item newCellItem(String id, int index, IModel model) {
            Item item;
            if (index == indexOfColumnYouWant){
                item = new Item(id, index, model) {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(IEvent<?> event) {
                        super.onEvent(event); 
                        if ((event.getPayload() instanceof AjaxUpdateEvent) ){
                            ((AjaxRequestTarget)event.getPayload()).add(item);
                        }
                    }
                };
            } else {
                item = super.newCellItem(id, index, model);
            } 

            return item;
        }
    };
```

Additionally you could also add the item to the target if it `isVisible()`.